# Why XML-Serializable class need a parameterless constructor

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization

I'm writing code to do Xml serialization. With below function.

```
public static string SerializeToXml(object obj)
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
    using (StringWriter writer = new StringWriter())
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, obj);
        return writer.ToString();
    }
}
```

If the argument is a instance of class without parameterless constructor, it will throw a exception.

> Unhandled Exception:
>   System.InvalidOperationException:
>   CSharpConsole.Foo cannot be serialized
>   because it does not have a
>   parameterless constructor.    at
>   System.Xml.Serialization.TypeDesc.CheckSupported()
>   at
>   System.Xml.Serialization.TypeScope.GetTypeDesc(Type
>   type, MemberInfo sourc e, Boolean
>   directReference, Boolean throwOnError)
>   at
>   System.Xml.Serialization.ModelScope.GetTypeModel(Type
>   type, Boolean direct Reference)    at
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportTypeMapping(Type
>   type , XmlRootAttribute root, String
>   defaultNamespace)    at
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer..ctor(Type
>   type, String defaultName space)    at
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer..ctor(Type
>   type)

Why must there be a parameterless constructor in order to allow xml serialization to succeed?

EDIT: thanks for cfeduke's answer. The parameterless constructor can be private or internal.

Comment: If you're interested, I found how to create objects without needing the constructor (see update) - but this won't help XmlSerializer at all - it still demands it. Useful for custom code, maybe.

Comment: `XmlSerializer` requires a default parameterless constructor for deserialization.

Comment: The **declaration** of the parameterless constructor is not required. Once a parameterized constructor is declared, the parameterless constructor must also be declared.

Answer (score 262, accepted):

During an object's de-serialization, the class responsible for de-serializing an object creates an instance of the serialized class and then proceeds to populate the serialized fields and properties only after acquiring an instance to populate.

You can make your constructor `private` or `internal` if you want, just so long as it's parameterless.

Comment: Oh, so, I can make the parameterless ctor private or internal and the serialization still works. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Yes I do it often, though I've come to accept that public parameterless constructors are great because they allow you to use "new()" with generics and the new initialization syntax.  For parametered constructors use static factory methods or the builder pattern implementation.

Comment: The accessibility tip is a good one, but your explanation makes no sense for serialization. An object needs to be created only for de-serialization.

I'd hazard a guess that the type-check code is built into the XmlSerializer constructor because a single instance can be used both ways.

Comment: Oh, I'll s/serialization/deserialization/ to make it clearer as to what I mean (was referring to serialization/deserialization as just "serialization" as an all encompassing term which isn't exactly correct and may lead to confusion).

Comment: @TomerGabel, what would be the point of serializing without deserializing? The type check exists to make sure when serializing that deserialization is possible.

Comment: @jwg One example is when you're sending your XML to a web service of some sort and are not interested in receiving those objects in your own component.

Comment: Keep in mind that even if you make your parameterless constructor `private` or `internal`, all of your properties whose values were serialized must have `public` setters.

Comment: How to overcome the situation where you already have parameterless constructor for normal construction in this fashion `public DerivedClass() : base(null) { }`

Answer (score 77):

This is a limitation of `XmlSerializer`. Note that `BinaryFormatter` and `DataContractSerializer` *do not* require this - they can create an uninitialized object out of the ether and initialize it during deserialization.

Since you are using xml, you might consider using `DataContractSerializer` and marking your class with `[DataContract]`/`[DataMember`], but note that this changes the schema (for example, there is no equivalent of `[XmlAttribute]` - everything becomes elements).

Update: if you really want to know, `BinaryFormatter` et al use [`FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatterservices.getuninitializedobject.aspx) to create the object without invoking the constructor. Probably dangerous; I don't recommend using it too often ;-p See also the remarks on MSDN:

> Because the new instance of the object
>   is initialized to zero and no
>   constructors are run, the object might
>   not represent a state that is regarded
>   as valid by that object. The current
>   method should only be used for
>   deserialization when the user intends
>   to immediately populate all fields. It
>   does not create an uninitialized
>   string, since creating an empty
>   instance of an immutable type serves
>   no purpose.

I have my [own](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/) serialization engine, but I don't intend making it use `FormatterServices`; I quite like knowing that a constructor (*any* constructor) has actually executed.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(Type). :)

Comment: Heh; turns out that I don't follow my own advice; protobuf-net has (optionally) allowed `FormatterServices` usage for *ages*

Comment: But what I don't understand is, in the case no constructor is specified, the compiler creates a public parameterless constructor. So why isn't that good enough for the xml deserialization engine?

Comment: If I want to deserialize XML and initialize certain object using their constructor (so that the elements/attributes are provided via the constructor), is there ANY way to achieve this? Isn't there a way to customize the serialization process so that it builds the objects using their constructors?

Comment: @Shimmy nope; that's not supported. There *is* `IXmlSerializable`, but a: that happens *after* the constructor, and b: it is very ugly and hard to get right (especially deserialization) - I strongly recommend against trying to implement that, but : it won't allow you to use constructors

Comment: Thanks. Any other means (besides XML) that allows deserialization via constructors?

Comment: What are the contents supposed to be for the parameterless constructor meant to satisfy XmlSerializer in the deserialization process?  Since people wrote some answers here but nobody mentioned the contents of the constructor presumably the contents of the constructor doesn't matter.  Suppose I have some complicated stuff in there so it gets executed but then it gets overwritten anyway by the object tree implied by the XML file?   If my interpretation is correct then the parameterless constructor only serves to make some space in memory.  Was it silly of .NET to execute that code?

Comment: @H2ONaCl you need to create an instance *somehow*. There is a way of doing it without invoking a constructor, but using a constructor allows for things like list initializers.

Comment: I created a space to describe the rules for the contents of the parameterless constructor.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66394177/what-are-the-rules-for-the-parameterless-constructor-invoked-by-xmlserializer

Answer (score 11):

The answer is: ***for no good reason whatsoever.***

Contrary to its name, the `XmlSerializer` class is used not only for serialization, but also for deserialization. It performs certain checks on your class to make sure that it will work, and some of those checks are only pertinent to deserialization, but it performs them all anyway, because it does not know what you intend to do later on.

The check that your class fails to pass is one of the checks that are only pertinent to deserialization.  Here is what happens:

- During deserialization, the `XmlSerializer` class will need to create
  instances of your type.
- In order to create an instance of a type, a constructor of that type
  needs to be invoked.
- If you did not declare a constructor, the compiler has already
  supplied a default parameterless constructor, but if you did declare
  a constructor, then that's the only constructor available.
- So, if the constructor that you declared accepts parameters, then the
  only way to instantiate your class is by invoking that constructor
  which accepts parameters.
- However, `XmlSerializer` is not capable of invoking any constructor
  except a parameterless constructor, because it does not know what
  parameters to pass to constructors that accept parameters.  So, it checks to see if your class has a parameterless constructor, and since it does not, it fails.

So, if the `XmlSerializer` class had been written in such a way as to only perform the checks pertinent to serialization, then your class would pass, because there is absolutely nothing about serialization that makes it necessary to have a parameterless constructor.

As others have already pointed out, the quick solution to your problem is to simply add a parameterless constructor. Unfortunately, it is also a dirty solution, because it means that you cannot have any `readonly` members initialized from constructor parameters.

In addition to all this, the `XmlSerializer` class *could* have been written in such a way as to allow even deserialization of classes without parameterless constructors.  All it would take would be to make use of ["The Factory Method Design Pattern" (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern). From the looks of it, Microsoft decided that this design pattern is far too advanced for DotNet programmers, who apparently should not be unnecessarily confused with such things. So, DotNet programmers should better stick to parameterless constructors, according to Microsoft.

Comment: Lol you say, `For no good reason whatsoever,` then go on to say, `XmlSerializer is not capable of invoking any constructor except a parameterless constructor, because it does not know what parameters to pass to constructors that accept parameters.` If it doesn't know what parameters to pass to a constructor, then how would it know what parameters to pass to a factory? Or which factory to use? I can't imagine this tool being more straightforward to use - you want a class deserialized, then let the deserializer make a default instance and then populate each field you tagged. Easy.

Comment: @Chuck you might want to ask another StackOverflow question "how does a factory method help me with constructor parameters" and let me know, I will answer it for you.

Answer (score 3):

Seems nobody actually read the original post... it is about SERIALIZATION and not DE-... and for this, no constructors are needed or called at all. The issue is simply poor coding practice from Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this what is written in [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.aspx). I think it is one of your class fields, not the main one - and how you want deserialiser to construct it back w/o parameterless construction ?

I think there is a workaround to make constructor private.

Answer (score 0):

I have this issue for
[error for serialization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCkvE.png)

I add a parameterless constructor to class and it's solved.

public Product(int code, string name)
{
Code = code;
Name = name;`//constructor elements`
}

public Product()
{`/////`
}

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35406117)