# Prevent calling Public constructors except for XML Serializer

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why XML-Serializable class need a parameterless constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267724/why-xml-serializable-class-need-a-parameterless-constructor)

Does anyone know if it is possible to prevent calling of a public constructor from outside a range of assemblies?

What I'm doing is coming up with a class library that has XML serializable classes. These classes make no sense if constructed without setting various properties so I want to prevent that state.

I'm wondering if there is a way to prevent anyone calling my public constructor, and keep it there only for serialization?

Comment: Is it required that the constructors be public, or could you make them internal?

Comment: If you do not explicitly call any constructor in the base class, the parameterless constructor will be called implicitly. There's no way around it, you cannot instantiate a class without a constructor being called.

Comment: Check this answer: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/267724/why-xml-serializable-class-need-a-parameterless-constructor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/267724/why-xml-serializable-class-need-a-parameterless-constructor). You may create internal or private constructor and still use XML serialization.

Comment: Removed accessibility tag, not valid for this question.

Comment: Apparently, they claim here they don't - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/267724/why-xml-serializable-class-need-a-parameterless-constructor

Comment: Why do you want to keep a constructor public, when you want to prevent it from being called?

Comment: I did not know that. I've always thought it had to be public, but I just tried it with an internal one, and it worked.

Comment: John. I'd be interested to know how you got that to work? All of my unit tests fail if I attempt to use anything but Public constructors.

Comment: I also tried it with private and it works. Could you post the exception?

Comment: System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object..

Comment: I just added a constructor, then tried it. I just realized I didn't try to deserialize. Hold five.

Comment: hmm, this may be a slightly different error though, because I use  element = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(elementType) as part of my custom serialization...

Comment: try (T)Activator.CreateInstance(elementType, true)

Comment: In XML Serialization? Odd. At any rate, deserialization works fine with the internal parameterless constructor.

Comment: ah. Thanks empi. Answered both my original, and the question I never asked but needed to know. :)

Comment: If your actual aim is to make it impossible to instantiate an object of your class except by calling certain constructors, [unfortunately that's impossible to ensure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatterservices.getuninitializedobject.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, I would create a public constructor with parameters that will make the object valid and create a public parameterless constructor with valid default values.

```
public foo() {
  this.bar = -1;
}

public foo(int bar) {
  this.bar = bar;
}
```

Private/internal constructor can be used depending on your situation, and you can create a Factory pattern that deals with object creation for external code.

Comment: +1 just because I agree that normally you should initalize sensible values, however in this situation the values are other classes, which need to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you are asking, you should probably make the constructor private, and then use a getInstance method to return the object if the correct assembly calls getInstance. You can do a check inside the getInstance method if you pass the object or assembly that called the function as one of its parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it would work in your case, but you could check the calling assembly:

```
if (Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().GetName().Name == "Forbidden.Assembly")
{
    throw new Exception(...);
}
```