# Type safety for Dictionary keys?

Tags: c#, generics, dictionary

I am planning to use multiple name-indexed dictionaries in a project.  My first choice was to use a `string` key, which is just the Name property of my `Value` elements.

However, this makes the dictionary keys identical even though they are accessing different types:

```
private Dictionary<string, Foo> myFoos;
private Dictionary<string, Bar> myBars;

myFoos[bar.Name];  // shouldn't be able to do this!
```

I would like the keys to be type-incompatible with each other to make them impossible to confuse with each other:

```
private Dictionary<FooName, Foo> myFoos;
private Dictionary<BarName, Bar> myBars;
```

Since creating a `*Name` class for each `Value` type is overkill, I created a `Name<T>` class:

```
public struct Name<T>
{
    public string Name;

    // for convenience, could be explicit instead
    static implicit operator string(Name<T> name)
    {
        return name.Name;
    }
}
```

which would give me

```
private Dictionary<Name<Foo>, Foo> myFoos;
private Dictionary<Name<Bar>, Bar> myBars;
```

and then I could store `Name<Foo>` instances instead of strings.

This seems a bit unwieldy, but it's the best I've come up with so far - any suggestions on how to do it better?
Is this misguided, or awesome?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first question is:

> I would like the keys to be type-incompatible with each other to make them impossible to confuse with each other:

*Why?* Is there actually a chance of confusion? This isn’t obvious. Mind you, I’m not saying that your method is bad; in fact, in fact, there are probably real benefits from this. But consider array indexers:

```
int a[];
float b[];
```

The types of the arrays are incompatible yet both use integer indices. And *yes*, this can actually lead to problems when the indices are confused – probably the same kinds of problems that you are facing with your keys.

So this case is exactly analogous to yours. Perhaps using the same key types for different containers isn’t that bad after all (even though in theory you are right and there’s the risk of confusion).

Comment: The problem presents itself when I want to store the list of Bars owned by a Foo.  Instead of storing a second copy of the Bars, I'm storing the Bar.Name - and a Dictionary<string, List<string>> starts to muddy the waters.

Comment: @mskfisher: that’s a bad approach. *Do* store the bars directly, not just their names! This is *not* making copies (unless your Foos and Bars are structures, which they shouldn’t be in this case). If they are classes, then your storing them will not make copies, it will merely store references to the objects. This is a fundamental property of object orientation and your use-case is so common that it has an own name: [aggregation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition).

Comment: @Konrad: Good catch, and another thing I should've mentioned.  I've been going back and forth between structs and classes on this design, since I want to pass copies between threads by value, not by reference.  I'm now looking into just going with classes and creating the copy constructor for each type I need to pass between threads.

Comment: @mskfisher It sounds like maybe you just need an immutable reference type for the best of both worlds?

Comment: Unfortunately, I need to be able to (de)serialize these objects with XmlSerializer/Deserializer, so they can't be immutable.  I think I'm just going to pretend they're immutable.

Comment: I'm going to look into what it'll take to load the XML manually instead of using XMLSerializer to load it.

Comment: [As per Marc Gravell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294308/immutability-and-xml-serialization/1294404#1294404), I'm going with a DTO.

Answer (score 5):

That will work, except that you need to override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` to make the names compare by value.