# How to serialize / deserialize immutable list type in c#

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, immutability, datacontractserializer

If I have a class defined

```
[DataContract()]
class MyObject {
    [DataMember()]
    ImmutableList<string> Strings { get; private set}
}
```

The `ImmutableList<T>` type comes from the immutables library https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Immutable. Note that the class ImmutableList does not have a default constructor or a mutable Add method. Adding things to the list take the form.

```
myList = myList.Add("new string");
```

Can I add some custom support to the .NET serialization mechanism to support this type and show it how to deserialize it?

Currently the collection is just skipped on deserialization though it is fine to serialize it.

Comment: Also, see [immutability-and-xml-serialization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294308/immutability-and-xml-serialization)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is another clean way to do this via [IDataContractSurrogate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.idatacontractsurrogate.aspx) interface. The DataContractSerializer allows you to provide a surrogate for non serializable objects. Below is the example and test case for `ImmutableList<T>`. It uses reflection and probably could be optimized by smarter folks than me but here it is.

**TESTCASE**

```
using FluentAssertions;
using System.Collections.Immutable;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using Xunit;

namespace ReactiveUI.Ext.Spec
{
    [DataContract(Name="Node", Namespace="http://foo.com/")]
    class Node
    {
        [DataMember()]
        public string Name;
    }

    [DataContract(Name="Fixture", Namespace="http://foo.com/")]
    class FixtureType
    {
        [DataMember()]
        public ImmutableList<Node> Nodes;

        public FixtureType(){
            Nodes = ImmutableList<Node>.Empty.AddRange( new []
            { new Node(){Name="A"}
            , new Node(){Name="B"}
            , new Node(){Name="C"}
            });
        }
    }


    public class ImmutableSurrogateSpec
    {  
        public static string ToXML(object obj)
            {
                var settings = new XmlWriterSettings { Indent = true };

                using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(memoryStream))
                using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(memoryStream, settings))
                {
                    DataContractSerializer serializer =
                      new DataContractSerializer
                          ( obj.GetType()
                          , new DataContractSerializerSettings() { DataContractSurrogate = new ImmutableSurrogateSerializer() }
                          );
                    serializer.WriteObject(writer, obj);
                    writer.Flush();
                    memoryStream.Position = 0;
                    return reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }

        public static T Load<T>(Stream data)
        {
            DataContractSerializer ser = new DataContractSerializer
                  ( typeof(T)
                  , new DataContractSerializerSettings() { DataContractSurrogate = new ImmutableSurrogateSerializer() }
                  );
            return (T)ser.ReadObject(data);
        }

        public static T Load<T>(string data)
        {
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data)))
            {
                return Load<T>(stream);
            }
        }

        [Fact]
        public void ShouldWork()
        {
            var o = new FixtureType();

            var s = ToXML(o);

            var oo = Load<FixtureType>(s);

            oo.Nodes.Count().Should().Be(3);
            var names = oo.Nodes.Select(n => n.Name).ToList();
            names.ShouldAllBeEquivalentTo(new[]{"A", "B", "C"});

        }

    }
}
```

**IMPLEMENTATION**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Immutable;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace ReactiveUI.Ext
{
    class ImmutableListListConverter<T>
    {
        public static ImmutableList<T> ToImmutable( List<T> list )
        {
            return ImmutableList<T>.Empty.AddRange(list);
        }

        public static List<T> ToList(ImmutableList<T> list){
            return list.ToList();
        }

        public static object ToImmutable( object list )
        {
            return ToImmutable(( List<T> ) list);
        }

        public static object ToList(object list){
            return ToList(( ImmutableList<T> ) list);
        }

    }

    static class ImmutableListListConverter {


        static ConcurrentDictionary<Tuple<string, Type>, Func<object,object>> _MethodCache 
            = new ConcurrentDictionary<Tuple<string, Type>, Func<object,object>>();

        public static Func<object,object> CreateMethod( string name, Type genericType )
        {
            var key = Tuple.Create(name, genericType);
            if ( !_MethodCache.ContainsKey(key) )
            {
                _MethodCache[key] = typeof(ImmutableListListConverter<>)
                    .MakeGenericType(new []{genericType})
                    .GetMethod(name, new []{typeof(object)})
                    .MakeLambda();
            }
            return _MethodCache[key];
        }
        public static Func<object,object> ToImmutableMethod( Type targetType )
        {
            return ImmutableListListConverter.CreateMethod("ToImmutable", targetType.GenericTypeArguments[0]);
        }

        public static Func<object,object> ToListMethod( Type targetType )
        {
            return ImmutableListListConverter.CreateMethod("ToList", targetType.GenericTypeArguments[0]);
        }

        private static Func<object,object> MakeLambda(this MethodInfo method )
        {
            return (Func<object,object>) method.CreateDelegate(Expression.GetDelegateType(
            (from parameter in method.GetParameters() select parameter.ParameterType)
            .Concat(new[] { method.ReturnType })
            .ToArray()));
        }

    }

    public class ImmutableSurrogateSerializer : IDataContractSurrogate
    {
        static ConcurrentDictionary<Type, Type> _TypeCache = new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, Type>();

        public Type GetDataContractType( Type targetType )
        {
            if ( _TypeCache.ContainsKey(targetType) )
            {
                return _TypeCache[targetType];
            }

            if(targetType.IsGenericType && targetType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ImmutableList<>)) 
            {
                return _TypeCache[targetType] 
                    = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(targetType.GetGenericArguments());
            }
            else
            {
                return targetType;
            }
        }

        public object GetDeserializedObject( object obj, Type targetType )
        {
            if ( _TypeCache.ContainsKey(targetType) )
            {
               return ImmutableListListConverter.ToImmutableMethod(targetType)(obj);
            }
            return obj;
        }

        public object GetObjectToSerialize( object obj, Type targetType )
        {
            if ( targetType.IsGenericType && targetType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ImmutableList<>) )
            {
               return ImmutableListListConverter.ToListMethod(targetType)(obj);
            }
            return obj;
        }

        public object GetCustomDataToExport( Type clrType, Type dataContractType )
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public object GetCustomDataToExport( System.Reflection.MemberInfo memberInfo, Type dataContractType )
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }


        public void GetKnownCustomDataTypes( System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<Type> customDataTypes )
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }


        public Type GetReferencedTypeOnImport( string typeName, string typeNamespace, object customData )
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public System.CodeDom.CodeTypeDeclaration ProcessImportedType( System.CodeDom.CodeTypeDeclaration typeDeclaration, System.CodeDom.CodeCompileUnit compileUnit )
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public ImmutableSurrogateSerializer() { }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's quite easy to prove it is working by commenting out the line that adds the surrogate to the serializer and watch the test fail.

Comment: Note I've stopped using Datacontract Serializer and now use the json.net serializers which "just work" for immutable collections.

Comment: Bit late, but are you sure `GetObjectToSerializer` shouldn't take both the actual type and the target type into account? I had to adjust that method to get the an ImmutableSurrogate to work with an ImmutableHashSet.

Comment: Based on this answer i've implemented the ISerializationSurrogateProvider interface for the .NET Standard library. It's basically the same as the IDataContractSurrogate interface for .Net 4.5. It should also perform a little bit better because we avoid coping the entire collection for serialization.
https://github.com/bp74/System.Collections.Immutable.Surrogate

Answer (score 4):

Heh; I can imagine what is happening here... the generated code is probably doing (paraphrasing):

```
var list = obj.Strings;
while(CanReadNextItem()) {
    list.Add(ReadNextItem());
}
```

The problem is that the BCL immutable API would require you to catch the result each time, i.e.

```
var list = obj.Strings;
while(CanReadNextItem()) {
    list = list.Add(ReadNextItem());
}
obj.Strings = list; // the private set is not a problem for this
```

Pre-existing list deserialization code doesn't work this way because it *has never needed to* - and indeed, there are many different implementations of `Add`, some of which return non-void results which are required to be ignored.

The lack of a non-public constructor may also upset it a bit, but if this was the *main problem*, I would kinda expect an exception when it tries to create a non-null list.

Of course, in performance terms, the `list = list.Add(...)` API *probably* isn't the most appropriate one to use *anyway* (although it should work).

I blogged on this topic recently (in the context of protobuf-net, which has now been updated to work with these collection types): http://marcgravell.blogspot.co.uk/2013/09/fun-with-immutable-collections.html Hopefully this blog article should explain why the differences mean that it doesn't play nicely with existing serialization techniques, and how serialization libraries might be updated to work with this scenario.

To answer the question directly, I would say the answer is simply: *because the required changes to support immutable collections have not yet been made to `DataContractSerializer`*. I have no knowledge of whether there is a plan to address this. But: I happily declare: "works in protobuf-net" ;p

Comment: The BCL libs have the Builder pattern where you can, within a transaction, go mutable. That would be the correct thing to do but there is no hook within DataContractSerializer to add this in myself :( ?

Comment: @bradgonesurfing yes, I discuss that (the builder API) fully in the blog. Frankly, I would be surprised if *any* serialization libraries had an extension point that was directly applicable to this situation. The changes I had to make to protobuf-net were beyond what could be achieved via surrogates, etc. And the fact that the builder API depends on knowledge of the non-generic utility class matching the generic concrete list means that it can't reasonably be expected to *just work* in serializers that didn't already know about this pattern.

Comment: My solution is to use a hidden private field as the actual ``DataMember`` and using the OnSerializing and OnDeserialized hooks proxy the immutable collection through the mutable list. It works and from a public interface perspective the collection it is still immutable.

Comment: @bradgonesurfing it makes a mess of the object, though; as per my other comment - I'd prefer to see a dedicated DTO model in that scenario

Comment: I agree. I've just found a hook for datacontract serializer surrogates http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.idatacontractsurrogate.aspx which is the official way to implement the hack pattern I did manually. Not sure I can get it to work for generics but I will give it a go.

Comment: I got it working with the surrogate serializer. It works very well. I'll add another answer as it is significantly different to the previous method.

Answer (score 4):

One way to do this is to use a proxy mutable list and use the OnSerializing and OnDeserialized hooks

```
[DataContract()]
class MyObject {

    public ImmutableList<string> Strings { get; private set}

    [DataMember(Name="Strings")]
    private List<String> _Strings;

    [OnSerializing()]
    public void OnSerializing(StreamingContext ctxt){
        _Strings = Strings.ToList();
    }

    [OnDeserialized()]
    public void OnDeserialized(StreamingContext ctxt){
        Strings = ImmutableList<string>.Empty.AddRange(_Strings);
    }
}
```

It's not super pretty but as Marc Gravell noted in his answer, <s>DataContract serializer is broken with respects to immutable collections and there are no simple hooks to teach it how to behave without the above type of hack.</s>

**UPDATE**

DataContract serializer is not broken. There is a way to hook surrogates in. See this separate answer showing an alternate technique.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18957739/158285

Comment: As a side note - my usual guidance is: if ever serialization steps outside of what can be done *trivially* with the chosen serializer, then rather than fighting it, create a separate DTO model (`MyObjectDTO`, for exmaple) that **does** play nicely with the serializer, and add conversion methods between the two models. So `MyObjectDTO` would have a simple `List<string>`, `MyObject` keeps the `ImmutableList<string>`, and the conversion code has the magic to switch between them.

Comment: Good advice but there is an API to handle this. IDataContractSurrogate. I just need to figure out how to write the code that maps ImmutableList<T> to List<T> and it should just work.