# how to convert ConcurrentDictionary to Dictionary at runtime?

Tags: c#

I know how to convert a ConcurrentDictionary to a Dictionary.

And I know that I can use reflection to determine if an object contains a ConcurrentDictionary.

But after I determined that an object does have a ConcurrentDictionary via reflection, how do I convert it to a Dictionary at runtime? Or can I do it at all? It's going to change the definition of the class, right?

Edit: I should have made it more clear. I'll show an example:

```
    [Serializable]
    [DataContract]
    public class CacheItem
    {
        [DataMember]
        private ConcurrentDictionary<string, CacheItemEntity> _cacheItemDictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, CacheItemEntity>();

        ......
    }
```

When I serialize an instance of this class, AVRO can't serialize the ConcurrentDictionary. So I wondered if I can convert the ConcurrentDictionary to a normal Dictionary at runtime. And this certainly changes the definition of the class. I'm just wondering if it can be done this way.

Comment: What is the motivation for wanting to convert the type?

Comment: @jdphenix, to be able to serialize objects that contain ConcurrentDictionary via microsoft AVRO library.

Comment: `var newDictionary = yourConcurrentDictionary.ToDictionary(kvp =>vp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);`

Comment: `var dictionary = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>(concurrentDictionary);`?

Comment: You can use `ToDictionary()` or the appropriate constructor of `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` as mentioned in comments. It's not really "converting" it though, but creating a new collection from a copy. If that's a good solution for you

Comment: @jdphenix I dont think he's looking for a deep clone.

Comment: @Damith: perhaps you should cast yourConcurrentDictionary to ConcurrentDictionary first, since its type is known only at runtime.

Comment: Your question is confusing, because you've said you know how to do A, and you know how to do B, but you want to know how to do B then A. Is the problem *actually* that you don't know the type arguments at compile-time, due to using reflection? What do you mean by "change the definition of the class" - are you trying to change the type of the field itself? It would really help if you could make this a lot clearer...

Comment: DataContractSerializer (used by AVRO I believe) can serialize ConcurrentDictionary AFAIK. Why do you need to change it to Dictionary?

Comment: @danish, it can't. I confirmed it with Microsoft.

Comment: @JonSkeet, I edited my question. Hopefully it cleared things up a little.

Comment: This sounds like it's quite an Avro-specific question - so that should be in your tags... my guess is that you should be implementing some specific serialization code.

Comment: @JonSkeet, the motivation is AVRO. But I wonder if doing such thing is possible or not.

Comment: Changing the type of a field (not just the value, but the actual *type* of a field)? Nope, basically not. Not unless you want to unload the appdomain, fiddle with the IL and reload it...

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18955441/how-to-serialize-deserialize-immutable-list-type-in-c-sharp)'s answers may have some useful advice in them.  [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18957739/15880) in particular.

Answer (score 3):

`ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>` implements `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` so anyplace you are trying to use a "dictionary" you can use the interface instead.  For example:

```
void ConsumeIDictionary(IDictionary dic)
{
   //perform work on a dictionary, regardless of the concrete type
}
```

You could call the method like this and it would be fine:

```
ConsumeIDictionary(new ConcurrentDictionary<int,int>());
```

Alternatively if you have a method that you want to use that requires the concrete `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` type, then you can use the [Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/et0ke8sz(v=vs.110).aspx) constructor that takes an existing IDictionary:

```
void ConsumeDictionary<K,V>(Dictionary<K,V> dic)
{
   //perform work on a concrete Dictionary
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
ConsumeDictionary(
   new Dictionary(
       new ConcurrentDictionary<int,int>()));
```

Just be aware that calling this constructor is an `O(n)` operation.

If you are trying to using reflection, you can determine that an object is a ConcurrentDictionary by examining the object's type at runtime via `GetType()`:

```
bool IsConcurrentDictionary<k, v>(obj o)
{
    return o.GetType() == typeof(ConcurrentDictionary<k,v>);
}
```

But in this case you may want to forget about the generic type parameters and just check for the `IDictionary` interface:

```
bool IsDictionary(obj o)
{
    return o is IDictionary;
}
```