# Design without default constructor

Tags: c#, default-constructor

I want to restrict creating object using default constructor. Because I have a desing like below:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BaseClass bc = new BaseClass("","");
        XmlSerializer xml = new XmlSerializer(typeof(BaseClass));
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(File.Create("c:\\test.txt"));
        xml.Serialize(sw,bc);
        sw.Flush();
        sw.Close();
    }
}
[Serializable]
public class BaseClass
{
    public string UserName, Password;
    // I don't want to create default constructor because of Authentication
    public BaseClass(string _UserName, string _Password)
    {
        UserName = _UserName;
        Password = _Password;
        f_Authenticate();
    }
    private void f_Authenticate() { }
}

public class DerivedClass:BaseClass
{
    public DerivedClass(string _UserName, string _Password) : base(_UserName, _Password)
    {
    }
}
```

This is ok. But when I make BaseClass to Serializable it'll generate this error:
`Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: ConsoleApplication1.BaseC
lass cannot be serialized because it does not have a parameterless constructor.`

Now my design is collapsing because I need to have `Username`, `Password` parameters but default constructor is ruining my design....

What should I do?

Comment: Actually I want to learn every possibilities. if I can/can't use what would you offer me?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/267724/why-xml-serializable-class-need-a-parameterless-constructor

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Create a private default constructor

```
private DerivedClass()
{
    // code
}
```

The serialzer will successfully call this even though it's private

Comment: No, because it requires a default constructor, thus it would be accessed publicly.

Comment: And to be completely thorough, you could add [Obsolete("Default constructor is only for serialization!", true)] to that private constructor, to ensure you don't accidentally call it from inside the class.

Comment: This is true also for WinForms `UserControl` (s) created in the designer. Having a private constructor will still allow to use them in the toolbox.

Answer (score 11):

The class deserializing your instances requires a parameterless constructor to create the instance, but you don't have to implement a public constructor -- it's enough to have a `private` or `internal` constructor as long as it needs no parameters.

By the way, you can as well use the [DataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx), which does not require a parameterless constructor and creates XML, too; it's always my primary choice :-)

Comment: I didn't realise this would be valid? I would of expected it to need a public constructor. Does this definitely work? If so, cool!

Comment: @TomWijsmanno, no, i meant by calling the non-default constructor (in OP's example), but i have removed my answer/comment as i realize that it is the serializer that calls the default constructor and hence it can't be private (i guess)

Comment: @Robbie - actually it can. It *does* call the constructor even if it is private and it *surely* sets private fields with the serialized values, even if you don't have a setter for this attribute.

Comment: @Matten in that case i'm undeleting my answer, i was faster than you ;)

Answer (score 1):

- Have you tried to create a private parameterless constructor?
- If there is the need of a public one, you can always comment saying that it should not be used (not the best solution)

You also need to create properties in your Serializable class. Variables are not considered and will not be read or written during serialization/deserealization process