# Why deserializing need public default constructor

Tags: c#, serialization, deserialization

In C# I know XML deserializing needs public default constructor. But why deserializing process needs a public constructor?

[sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10088302/design-without-default-constructor)

Comment: See [this KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/330592).

Answer (score 1):

Because it uses it to create an instance of the type.

Answer (score 0):

Because `XmlSerializer` uses that constructor to initialize your class and then set the properties.