# How to exclude specific types from serialization?

Tags: .net, serialization, .net-4.0, sgen

I run `sgen` against my assembly with a metric ton of types. I want to exclude 2 types from serialization.  I don't seem to be able to find a way to do it.

I see that `sgen` has a `/type` switch to specify a specific type, but nothing to exclude a specific type.

Is there a way to exclude specific types from serialization?

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand your question, but `sgen` only generates the serialization assembly. What is the problem with having another two classes in there?

Comment: In case you want to do this because SGEN complains about identical class names, then open your .csproj file and you may find `<SGenUseProxyTypes>false</SGenUseProxyTypes>` tags. I removed those while leaving `<GenerateSerializationAssemblies>On</GenerateSerializationAssemblies>` alone and the errors went away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from putting the types you wish to exclude in a different assembly, you cannot exclude types from the serializer generation.

**Update**

Other posters have come up with additional possibilities to exclude specific types, with varying applicability based on your use case.

Comment: I know this is old. But what about removing parameter less constructor? That appears to prevent sgen processing class.

Comment: @Tom Yes, this works for me. Consider posting a respective answer - I'll upvote.

Answer (score 1):

You can try changing the access of the classes you want to exclude from Xml Serialization by marking the class as `internal`, then sgen.exe should skip that class.

```
internal class NotToBeSerialized
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: But I need to exclude generation for types which I need to use from another assembly.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent the class being included in sgen processing, ensure it doesn't have a parameterless constructor.

As explained by the answer to this question [Why XML-Serializable class need a parameterless constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/267724/361714), serialization requires a parameter less constructor, of any permission level, to work. **Making the paramaterless constructor private isn't sufficient**, to exclude if from sgen processing.

Answer (score -6):

Not sure if you are looking for this but you can exclude your own classes from serialization by mentioning [NonSerialized] before class definition.
So if you want to exclude a specific type you will have to inherit from it and create your own class

```
[NonSerialized]
public class Point
{
    public int x, y;
}
```

Comment: This code should not compile, because the `NonSerialized` attribute's only targets are fields.

Comment: Error 2 Attribute 'NonSerialized' is not valid on this declaration type. It is only valid on 'field' declarations.