# c# xml serialization : ignore a class

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I am using sgen.exe to generate a serializer for the classes of my project. Many classes have to be serizalized, and many others don't.

The attribute `[XmlIgnore]` doesn't works on classes, so is there a way to do it?

thanks

Comment: Code example maybe ?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of is adding the XmlIgnore attribute to each property you do not want serialised. Not sure if sgen allows you to specify classes to ignore but I was having a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11569766/how-to-exclude-specific-types-from-serialization).

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I have tried it and it doesn't works : sgen.exe still tries to build a serializer for the class.