# Serializing multiple nested XmlArrays in C#

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, nested, xml-serialization

I am trying to do serialize a class that contains a List with nested Tuples with arrays of DateTimes as keys and doubles as values.

Below is a basic version of the code:

Class:

```
[XmlRoot("Foo")]
public class Foo
{
    [XmlArray("Pairs")]
    [XmlArrayItem(typeof(Tuple<DateTime[], double>), ElementName = "Pair")]
    [XmlArrayItem(typeof(DateTime), ElementName = "DateRange"), XmlArrayItem(typeof(double), ElementName = "Value")]
    public List<Tuple<DateTime[], double>> pairs;
}
```

Main:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Foo f = new Foo();
        f.pairs = new List<Tuple<DateTime[], double>>();

        f.pairs.Add(
            new Tuple<DateTime[], double>(
                new DateTime[2]{
                    new DateTime(2014,1,1),
                    new DateTime(2014,1,3),
                },
                1.1
            ));

        f.pairs.Add(
            new Tuple<DateTime[], double>(
                new DateTime[2]{
                    new DateTime(2014,2,1),
                    new DateTime(2014,2,3),
                },
                2.2
            ));

        System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer writer =
            new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(Foo));

        System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(
            @"C:/Users/x/Desktop/test.xml");


    }
}
```

I am getting a reflecting error and I think the issue is that I am not using the attributes correctly as there are too many nested arrays.

Is there a way to make this work, or would I need to create separate serializable classes and nest those within one another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error I'm getting is not about nested arrays. When you look at the Inner exceptions you will eventually arrive at:

```
System.Tuple`2[System.DateTime[],System.Double] cannot be serialized 
because it does not have a parameterless constructor.
```

[Why I could not serialize a tuple in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13739348/why-i-could-not-serialize-a-tuple-in-c)

So I am afraid you will have to change your designs ...

Comment: Thanks Darek. I really should have looked a bit harder, but is there no way around this?

Comment: I'm afraid there is none. To serialize you must have a parameter-less constructor, because first a default instance is created, than all properties filled in with deserialized data.