# Serializing Exception - Cannot be serialized because it does not have a parameterless constructor

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, exchangewebservices, xmlserializer

I'm getting an exception when initializing an `XMLSerializer` and passing it an instance of `Appointment` (from the EWS API):

> Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Appointment cannot be serialized because it does not have a parameterless constructor.

Here is my code:

```
private static string FindAppointmentsAsXmlString(CalendarView calendar, ExchangeService serv)
{
    FindItemsResults<Appointment> appointments = serv.FindAppointments(
        WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, calendar);
    List<Appointment> appointmentsList = appointments.ToList();

    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(appointmentsList.GetType());
    var writer = new StringWriter();

    try
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, appointmentsList);
        Console.WriteLine(writer.GetStringBuilder().ToString());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    return writer.GetStringBuilder().ToString(); 
}
```

Comment: @GrantWinney I don't get how that helps me, unless you can provide some insight?

Comment: ...And I just ran my application again and it's "parameterless". My fault! Ah!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use AutoMapper, either get it by Nuget or https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper
if you do  :-

```
namespace DTO
    {        
        public class CalendarAppointment : Appointment
        {
            public CalendarAppointment() : base( /* any parameters to construct the base appointment, doesn't matter /* )
            {
            }
        }
}
```

then you can do

```
private static string FindAppointmentsAsXmlString(CalendarView calendar, ExchangeService serv)
        {
            FindItemsResults<Appointment> appointments = serv.FindAppointments(
                WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, calendar);

            Mapper.CreateMap<Appointment, DTO.CalendarAppointment>();

            var list = appointments.Select(Mapper.Map<DTO.CalendarAppointment>).ToList();
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(list.GetType());
            var writer = new StringWriter();

            try
            {
                serializer.Serialize(writer, list);
                Console.WriteLine(writer.GetStringBuilder().ToString());
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }

            return writer.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason I linked to the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267724/why-xml-serializable-class-need-a-parameterless-constructor) in my comment above *(since deleted)* is that it states that:

> During an object's de-serialization, the class responsible for de-serializing an object creates an instance of the serialized class and then proceeds to populate the serialized fields and properties only after acquiring an instance to populate.

You can see from the documentation of the [Appointment constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.appointment.appointment%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) that `Appointment` requires an instance of `ExchangeService` in the constructor... there is no parameterless constructor, hence the error.

I don't know about all the inner-workings of the serialization process, but hopefully this gives you a reason for the error at least.

Normally, if it were your own class, you should just be able to add an additional (parameterless) constructor, but I'm not sure what you do in this case. There may very well be another way to successfully serialize the `Appointment` class, but I'm not sure.

You could try extending the `Appointment` class, providing a parameterless constructor in there, and then serialize that using XML. I'm not sure it'll work, but maybe someone else can provide a more definite answer.

```
public class MyAppointment : Appointment
{
    public MyAppointment() { }
}
```

If I find anything else on it, I'll update this.

Comment: Thanks Grant, very helpful! I'm Serializing the Appointment object as I'm writing the contents to an XML file, is there an alternative way, avoiding this exception, to write the object's contents to an XML file?

Comment: Thanks for your help @GrantWinney, I did have an alternative thought - run through a List of type Appointments, convert each node to String, then Serialize? Also when implementing a class which extends Appointment, the result is: "'Microsoft.Exchange...Appointment' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments"

Comment: I'll give it a go, I don't see how that wouldn't work. Cheers!