# Serialize a ISerializable class without parameterless constructor

Tags: c#, serialization, emgucv

I am using a class which implements `ISerializable` but does not have a parameterless constructor. The class is from **EmguCV** library:

```
[Serializable]
public class DenseHistogram : UnmanagedObject, ISerializable, IEquatable<DenseHistogram>
{
    public DenseHistogram(int binSize, RangeF range);
    public DenseHistogram(int[] binSizes, RangeF[] ranges);
    public DenseHistogram(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context);
}
```

As you may guess I get a "*Emgu.CV.DenseHistogram cannot be serialized because it does not have a parameterless constructor.*" exception. I know that -and why- I need the parameterless constructor but it kind of makes me confused since the class implements `ISerializable`.

Comment: The last constructor seems to be about serialization.

Comment: do I need to do anything special to serialize it then?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/267727/2189576

Comment: @shfire , i'm not the developer of that class

Comment: @paulsimmons then you need another serialization method (that should only be a problem for some like the mentioned XmlSerializer) or you need to wrap the class (facade)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is for [binary serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72hyey7b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) through the [`BinaryFormatter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), not the more familiar serialization through `XmlSerializer`.

Some information here: [Custom serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty01x675%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  By default binary serialization serializes the *fields* of classes, `ISerializable` allows this to be overridden, for instance when serializing between different versions.