# XML Deserialization of attributes

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

I have a complicated XML structure with hierarchical Process, Stage, Step, Task as follows:

```
<Process>
    <Stage StageName="Data gathering" StagePage="page_DA.html" Status="Not Started" Selected="true">
        <StageUsers>
            <User Alias="PNeelakandan" FullName="Prasaanth Neelakandan" Role="Dev" Email="PNeelakandan@exchange.com" Organization="Windows"/>
            <User Alias="SGuo3" FullName="Wen Jiao" Role="Dev" Email="SGuo3@exchange.com" Organization="Windows"/>
        </StageUsers>
        <Step StepName="Data acquistion - General" StepPage="page_DAGeneral.html" Status="Not Started">
            <StepUsers>
                <User Alias="PNeelakandan" FullName="Prasaanth Neelakandan" Role="Dev" Email="PNeelakandan@exchange.com" Organization="Windows"/>
                <User Alias="SGuo3" FullName="Wen Jiao" Role="Dev" Email="SGuo3@exchange.com" Organization="Windows"/>
            </StepUsers>
            <Task TaskName="Well locations and reference elevations" TaskTip="Well locations and reference elevations" Status="Not Started">
                <TaskUsers>
                    <User Alias="PNeelakandan" FullName="Prasaanth Neelakandan" Role="Dev" Email="PNeelakandan@exchange.com" Organization="Windows"/>
                    <User Alias="SGuo3" FullName="Wen Jiao" Role="Dev" Email="SGuo3@exchange.com" Organization="Windows"/>
                </TaskUsers>
            </Task>
            <Task TaskName="Well deviation surveys" TaskTip="Well deviation surveys" Status="Not Started">
                <TaskUsers>
                    <User Alias="PNeelakandan" FullName="Prasaanth Neelakandan" Role="Dev" Email="PNeelakandan@exchange.com" Organization="Windows"/>
                    <User Alias="SGuo3" FullName="Wen Jiao" Role="Dev" Email="SGuo3@exchange.com" Organization="Windows"/>
                </TaskUsers>
            </Task>
        </Step>
        <Step StepName="Data acquistion - Petrophysics" StepPage="page_DAPetro.html" Status="Not Started">
            <StepUsers>
                <User Alias="PNeelakandan" FullName="Prasaanth Neelakandan" Role="Dev" Email="PNeelakandan@exchange.com" Organization="Windows"/>
                <User Alias="SGuo3" FullName="Wen Jiao" Role="Dev" Email="SGuo3@exchange.com" Organization="Windows"/>
            </StepUsers>
            <Task TaskName="Digitization of maps and logs" TaskTip="Digitization of maps and logs" Status="Not Started">
                <TaskUsers>
                    <User Alias="PNeelakandan" FullName="Prasaanth Neelakandan" Role="Dev" Email="PNeelakandan@exchange.com" Organization="Windows"/>
                    <User Alias="SGuo3" FullName="Wen Jiao" Role="Dev" Email="SGuo3@exchange.com" Organization="Windows"/>
                </TaskUsers>
            </Task>
            <Task TaskName="Log data loading" TaskTip="Log data loading" Status="Not Started">
                <TaskUsers>
                    <User Alias="PNeelakandan" FullName="Prasaanth Neelakandan" Role="Dev" Email="PNeelakandan@exchange.com" Organization="Windows"/>
                    <User Alias="SGuo3" FullName="Wen Jiao" Role="Dev" Email="SGuo3@exchange.com" Organization="Windows"/>
                </TaskUsers>
            </Task>
            <Task TaskName="Special core analysis" TaskTip="Special core analysis" Status="Not Started">
                <TaskUsers>
                    <User Alias="PNeelakandan" FullName="Prasaanth Neelakandan" Role="Dev" Email="PNeelakandan@exchange.com" Organization="Windows"/>
                    <User Alias="SGuo3" FullName="Wen Jiao" Role="Dev" Email="SGuo3@exchange.com" Organization="Windows"/>
                </TaskUsers>
            </Task>
        </Step>
        <Step StepName="Data acquistion - Geology" StepPage="page_DAGeology.html" Status="Not Started">
            <StepUsers>
                <User Alias="PNeelakandan" FullName="Prasaanth Neelakandan" Role="Dev" Email="PNeelakandan@exchange.com" Organization="Windows"/>
                <User Alias="SGuo3" FullName="Wen Jiao" Role="Dev" Email="SGuo3@exchange.com" Organization="Windows"/>
            </StepUsers>
            <Task TaskName="Stratigraphic correlations" TaskTip="Stratigraphic correlations" Status="Not Started">
                <TaskUsers>
                    <User Alias="PNeelakandan" FullName="Prasaanth Neelakandan" Role="Dev" Email="PNeelakandan@exchange.com" Organization="Windows"/>
                    <User Alias="SGuo3" FullName="Wen Jiao" Role="Dev" Email="SGuo3@exchange.com" Organization="Windows"/>
                </TaskUsers>
            </Task>
            <Task TaskName="Core data" TaskTip="Core data" Status="Not Started">
                <TaskUsers>
                    <User Alias="PNeelakandan" FullName="Prasaanth Neelakandan" Role="Dev" Email="PNeelakandan@exchange.com" Organization="Windows"/>
                    <User Alias="SGuo3" FullName="Wen Jiao" Role="Dev" Email="SGuo3@exchange.com" Organization="Windows"/>
                </TaskUsers>
            </Task>
            <Task TaskName="Geochemistry data" TaskTip="Geochemistry data" Status="Not Started">
                <TaskUsers>
                    <User Alias="PNeelakandan" FullName="Prasaanth Neelakandan" Role="Dev" Email="PNeelakandan@exchange.com" Organization="Windows"/>
                    <User Alias="SGuo3" FullName="Wen Jiao" Role="Dev" Email="SGuo3@exchange.com" Organization="Windows"/>
                </TaskUsers>
            </Task>
            <Task TaskName="Dip interpretation data" TaskTip="Dip interpretation data" Status="Not Started">
                <TaskUsers>
                    <User Alias="PNeelakandan" FullName="Prasaanth Neelakandan" Role="Dev" Email="PNeelakandan@exchange.com" Organization="Windows"/>
                    <User Alias="SGuo3" FullName="Wen Jiao" Role="Dev" Email="SGuo3@exchange.com" Organization="Windows"/>
                </TaskUsers>
            </Task>
            <Task TaskName="Existing digital time or depth structure maps" TaskTip="Existing digital time or depth structure maps" Status="Not Started">
                <TaskUsers>
                    <User Alias="PNeelakandan" FullName="Prasaanth Neelakandan" Role="Dev" Email="PNeelakandan@exchange.com" Organization="Windows"/>
                    <User Alias="SGuo3" FullName="Wen Jiao" Role="Dev" Email="SGuo3@exchange.com" Organization="Windows"/>
                </TaskUsers>
            </Task>
            <Task TaskName="Existing digital property maps" TaskTip="Existing digital property maps" Status="Not Started">
                <TaskUsers>
                    <User Alias="PNeelakandan" FullName="Prasaanth Neelakandan" Role="Dev" Email="PNeelakandan@exchange.com" Organization="Windows"/>
                    <User Alias="SGuo3" FullName="Wen Jiao" Role="Dev" Email="SGuo3@exchange.com" Organization="Windows"/>
                </TaskUsers>
            </Task>
        </Step>
        <Step StepName="Data acquistion - Geophysics" StepPage="page_DAGeophysics.html" Status="Not Started">
            <StepUsers>
                <User Alias="PNeelakandan" FullName="Prasaanth Neelakandan" Role="Dev" Email="PNeelakandan@exchange.com" Organization="Windows"/>
                <User Alias="SGuo3" FullName="Wen Jiao" Role="Dev" Email="SGuo3@exchange.com" Organization="Windows"/>
            </StepUsers>
            <Task TaskName="Seismic data loading" TaskTip="Seismic data loading" Status="Not Started">
                <TaskUsers>
                    <User Alias="PNeelakandan" FullName="Prasaanth Neelakandan" Role="Dev" Email="PNeelakandan@exchange.com" Organization="Windows"/>
                    <User Alias="SGuo3" FullName="Wen Jiao" Role="Dev" Email="SGuo3@exchange.com" Organization="Windows"/>
                </TaskUsers>
            </Task>
            <Task TaskName="Stacking velocity ata loading" TaskTip="Stacking velocity ata loading" Status="Not Started">
                <TaskUsers>
                    <User Alias="PNeelakandan" FullName="Prasaanth Neelakandan" Role="Dev" Email="PNeelakandan@exchange.com" Organization="Windows"/>
                    <User Alias="SGuo3" FullName="Wen Jiao" Role="Dev" Email="SGuo3@exchange.com" Organization="Windows"/>
                </TaskUsers>
            </Task>
            <Task TaskName="VSP or check shot data" TaskTip="VSP or check shot data" Status="Not Started">
                <TaskUsers>
                    <User Alias="PNeelakandan" FullName="Prasaanth Neelakandan" Role="Dev" Email="PNeelakandan@exchange.com" Organization="Windows"/>
                    <User Alias="SGuo3" FullName="Wen Jiao" Role="Dev" Email="SGuo3@exchange.com" Organization="Windows"/>
                </TaskUsers>
            </Task>
        </Step>
        <Step StepName="Data acquistion - Engineering" StepPage="page_DAEng.html" Status="Not Started">
            <StepUsers>
                <User Alias="PNeelakandan" FullName="Prasaanth Neelakandan" Role="Dev" Email="PNeelakandan@exchange.com" Organization="Windows"/>
                <User Alias="SGuo3" FullName="Wen Jiao" Role="Dev" Email="SGuo3@exchange.com" Organization="Windows"/>
            </StepUsers>
            <Task TaskName="Drilling and completion data" TaskTip="Drilling and completion data" Status="Not Started">
                <TaskUsers>
                    <User Alias="PNeelakandan" FullName="Prasaanth Neelakandan" Role="Dev" Email="PNeelakandan@exchange.com" Organization="Windows"/>
                    <User Alias="SGuo3" FullName="Wen Jiao" Role="Dev" Email="SGuo3@exchange.com" Organization="Windows"/>
                </TaskUsers>
            </Task>
            <Task TaskName="Pressure transient data" TaskTip="Pressure transient data" Status="Not Started">
                <TaskUsers>
                    <User Alias="PNeelakandan" FullName="Prasaanth Neelakandan" Role="Dev" Email="PNeelakandan@exchange.com" Organization="Windows"/>
                    <User Alias="SGuo3" FullName="Wen Jiao" Role="Dev" Email="SGuo3@exchange.com" Organization="Windows"/>
                </TaskUsers>
            </Task>
            <Task TaskName="Production data" TaskTip="Production data" Status="Not Started">
                <TaskUsers>
                    <User Alias="PNeelakandan" FullName="Prasaanth Neelakandan" Role="Dev" Email="PNeelakandan@exchange.com" Organization="Windows"/>
                    <User Alias="SGuo3" FullName="Wen Jiao" Role="Dev" Email="SGuo3@exchange.com" Organization="Windows"/>
                </TaskUsers>
            </Task>
            <Task TaskName="Pressure data" TaskTip="Pressure data" Status="Not Started">
                <TaskUsers>
                    <User Alias="PNeelakandan" FullName="Prasaanth Neelakandan" Role="Dev" Email="PNeelakandan@exchange.com" Organization="Windows"/>
                    <User Alias="SGuo3" FullName="Wen Jiao" Role="Dev" Email="SGuo3@exchange.com" Organization="Windows"/>
                </TaskUsers>
            </Task>
            <Task TaskName="Sample chracterization" TaskTip="Sample chracterization" Status="Not Started">
                <TaskUsers>
                    <User Alias="PNeelakandan" FullName="Prasaanth Neelakandan" Role="Dev" Email="PNeelakandan@exchange.com" Organization="Windows"/>
                    <User Alias="SGuo3" FullName="Wen Jiao" Role="Dev" Email="SGuo3@exchange.com" Organization="Windows"/>
                </TaskUsers>
            </Task>
        </Step>
        <Step StepName="Data acquistion - Additional" StepPage="page_DAAdd.html" Status="Not Started">
            <StepUsers>
                <User Alias="PNeelakandan" FullName="Prasaanth Neelakandan" Role="Dev" Email="PNeelakandan@exchange.com" Organization="Windows"/>
                <User Alias="SGuo3" FullName="Wen Jiao" Role="Dev" Email="SGuo3@exchange.com" Organization="Windows"/>
            </StepUsers>
            <Task TaskName="New cores" TaskTip="New cores" Status="Not Started">
                <TaskUsers>
                    <User Alias="PNeelakandan" FullName="Prasaanth Neelakandan" Role="Dev" Email="PNeelakandan@exchange.com" Organization="Windows"/>
                    <User Alias="SGuo3" FullName="Wen Jiao" Role="Dev" Email="SGuo3@exchange.com" Organization="Windows"/>
                </TaskUsers>
            </Task>
            <Task TaskName="Special core analysis for Geomechanics" TaskTip="Special core analysis for Geomechanics" Status="Not Started">
                <TaskUsers>
                    <User Alias="PNeelakandan" FullName="Prasaanth Neelakandan" Role="Dev" Email="PNeelakandan@exchange.com" Organization="Windows"/>
                    <User Alias="SGuo3" FullName="Wen Jiao" Role="Dev" Email="SGuo3@exchange.com" Organization="Windows"/>
                </TaskUsers>
            </Task>
            <Task TaskName="Core sampling" TaskTip="Core sampling" Status="Not Started">
                <TaskUsers>
                    <User Alias="PNeelakandan" FullName="Prasaanth Neelakandan" Role="Dev" Email="PNeelakandan@exchange.com" Organization="Windows"/>
                    <User Alias="SGuo3" FullName="Wen Jiao" Role="Dev" Email="SGuo3@exchange.com" Organization="Windows"/>
                </TaskUsers>
            </Task>
            <Task TaskName="Laboratory tests" TaskTip="Laboratory tests" Status="Not Started">
                <TaskUsers>
                    <User Alias="PNeelakandan" FullName="Prasaanth Neelakandan" Role="Dev" Email="PNeelakandan@exchange.com" Organization="Windows"/>
                    <User Alias="SGuo3" FullName="Wen Jiao" Role="Dev" Email="SGuo3@exchange.com" Organization="Windows"/>
                </TaskUsers>
            </Task>
        </Step>
    </Stage>
    <Stage StageName="Well reservoir production review" StagePage="page_WRPR.html" Status="Not Started" Selected="true">
        <StageUsers>
            <User Alias="PNeelakandan" FullName="Prasaanth Neelakandan" Role="Dev" Email="PNeelakandan@exchange.com" Organization="Windows"/>
            <User Alias="SGuo3" FullName="Wen Jiao" Role="Dev" Email="SGuo3@exchange.com" Organization="Windows"/>
        </StageUsers>
    </Stage>
</Process>
```

Basically , a Process is made of Stages . And Stages are made of Steps and Steps are made of Tasks. Each of these have some assigned Users and some attributes like Name , page , status .etc.

All of these have their own classes :

```
public class Process
{
    public string ProcessName { get; set; }
    public string HelpFile { get; set; }
    public List<Stage> Stages { get; set; }
    public Process()
    {
        Stages = new List<Stage>();
    }

    public XElement GenerateXML()
    {
        var proc = new XElement("Process");

        foreach (Stage stg in Stages)
        {
            proc.Add(stg.GenerateXML());
        }

        // this returns the final Process XML
        return proc;
    }
}
```

Stage Class :

```
public class Stage
{
    public string StageName { get; set; }
    public string stagepage { get; set; }
    public List<Step> Steps { get; set; }
    public List<User> StageUsers { get; set; }
    public string StageStatus { get; set; }

    public bool IsSelected;

    public Stage(String name)
    {
        StageName = name;
        Steps = new List<Step>();
        StageUsers = new List<User>();
        Selected = true;
    }
    public XElement GenerateXML()
    {
        var proj = new XElement("Stage",
            new XAttribute("StageName", StageName),
            new XAttribute("StagePage", stagepage),
            new XAttribute("Status", StageStatus), 
            new XAttribute("Selected", IsSelected)
            );
        var users = new XElement("StageUsers");
        foreach (User stgUser in StageUsers)
        {
            users.Add(stgUser.GenerateXML());
        }
        proj.Add(users);

        foreach (Step st in Steps)
        {
            proj.Add(st.GenerateXML());
        }
        return proj;
    }
}
```

Step Class :

```
public class Step
{
    public string StepName { get; set; }
    public string StepPage { get; set; }
    public List<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
    public List<User> StepUsers { get; set; }
    public string StepStatus { get; set; }

    public Step(String name)
    {
        StepName = name;
        Tasks = new List<Task>();
        StepUsers=new List<User>();
    }

    public XElement GenerateXML()
    {
        var proj = new XElement("Step",
            new XAttribute("StepName", StepName),
            new XAttribute("StepPage", StepPage),
            new XAttribute("Status", StepStatus)
            );
        var users = new XElement("StepUsers");
        foreach (User stpUser in StepUsers)
        {
            users.Add(stpUser.GenerateXML());
        }
        proj.Add(users);

        foreach (Task tk in Tasks)
        {
            proj.Add(tk.GenerateXML());
        }
        return proj;
    }
}
```

Task Class:

```
public class Task
{
    public string TaskTip { get; set; }
    public string TaskName { get; set; }
    public List<User> TaskUsers { get; set; }
    public string TaskStatus { get; set; }
    public Task(String name)
    {
        TaskName = name;
        TaskUsers = new List<User>();
    }

    public XElement GenerateXML()
    {
        var proj = new XElement("Task",
            new XAttribute("TaskName", TaskName),
            new XAttribute("TaskTip", TaskTip)
           ,
            new XAttribute("Status", TaskStatus)
            );

        var users = new XElement("TaskUsers");
        foreach (User tkUser in TaskUsers)
        {
            users.Add(tkUser.GenerateXML());
        }
        proj.Add(users);
        return proj;
    }
}
```

And the User class :

```
public class User
{
    public string Alias { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; }
    public string Organization { get; set; }

    public XElement GenerateXML()
    {
        var proj = new XElement("User",
          new XAttribute("Alias", Alias),
          new XAttribute("FullName", FullName),
          new XAttribute("Role", Role),
          new XAttribute("Email", Email),
          new XAttribute("Organization", Organization)
          );

        return proj;
    }
}
```

I have written GenerateXML() methods for eahc step to get the final XML displayed above (when called from EFDP User).

My question is : Is there a way I can read the above XML into the respective classes and objects as shown ? I tried my hand at XML Serialization but could not figure out how to do this for the attributes?
I could always try a brute force way of reading this into objects but that would be very lengthy.

If I could get any ideas on this or if I could get any suggestions to improve the above design to enable reading XML into objects easily that would be great.

```
public class Reviewer
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Verdict { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Comments { get; set; }

    [XmlElement]
    public User User { get; set; }

    public Reviewer()
    {
        User = new User();
    }
}
```

Comment: In the future, rather than asking one giant question like "how to I convert multiple classes into specific XML for each class", try to break down your question into specific problems, like "how do I serialize a property of a class as an attribute".

Comment: And don't post so much code! Do you really expect every reader to read all of that? Just post enough to reproduce the problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`XmlSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to serialize a property of a class as an XML attribute by applying the [`[XmlAttribute]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributeattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): attribute to the property:

```
public class User
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Alias { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Role { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Organization { get; set; }
}
```

For more information on controlling and customizing XML serialization of .Net classes, see here: [Attributes That Control XML Serialization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83y7df3e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Having done that, you can now serialize your class to an `XElement` or an XML string using extension methods such as the following:

```
public static class XmlSerializationExtensions
{
    public static string ToXml<T>(this T obj)
    {
        return obj.ToXml(false);
    }

    public static string ToXml<T>(this T obj, bool omitStandardNamespaces)
    {
        using (var textWriter = new StringWriter())
        {
            var settings = new XmlWriterSettings() { Indent = true, IndentChars = "  " }; // For cosmetic purposes.
            using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(textWriter, settings))
            {
                XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = null;
                if (omitStandardNamespaces)
                    (ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces()).Add("", ""); // Disable the xmlns:xsi and xmlns:xsd lines.
                new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType()).Serialize(writer, obj, ns);
            }
            return textWriter.ToString();
        }
    }

    public static T DeserializeXML<T>(this string xmlString)
    {
        using (var reader = new StringReader(xmlString))
        {
            var result = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T)).Deserialize(reader);
            if (result is T)
                return (T)result;
        }
        return default(T);
    }

    public static XElement ToXElement<T>(this T obj)
    {
        return obj.ToXElement(true);
    }

    public static XElement ToXElement<T>(this T obj, bool omitStandardNamespaces)
    {
        var doc = new XDocument();
        using (var writer = doc.CreateWriter())
        {
            XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = null;
            if (omitStandardNamespaces)
                (ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces()).Add("", ""); // Disable the xmlns:xsi and xmlns:xsd lines.
            new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType()).Serialize(writer, obj, ns);
        }
        var element = doc.Root;
        if (element != null)
            element.Remove();
        return element;
    }

    public static T DeserializeXML<T>(this XContainer element)
    {
        using (var reader = element.CreateReader())
        {
            var result = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T)).Deserialize(reader);
            if (result is T)
                return (T)result;
        }
        return default(T);
    }
}
```

Then you can use the extension methods like so:

```
        var user = new User { Alias = "foo", Email = "bar@none.net", FullName = "full name name", Organization = "disorganized", Role = "forward" };
        var xml = user.ToXml();
        Debug.WriteLine(xml);
        var xElement = user.ToXElement();
        Debug.WriteLine(xElement);
```

Or, to deserialize:

```
        var process1 = xmlString.DeserializeXML<Process>();
        var process2 = xmlElement.DeserializeXML<Process>();
```

**Update**

In order to use `XmlSerializer`, all your classes must have a public (possibly default) [parameterless constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267724/why-xml-serializable-class-need-a-parameterless-constructor).  Also, in your XML, some of your lists are one level deep while some are two levels deep.  One-level-deep lists need to be decorated with the `XmlElement` attribute, like so:

```
    [XmlElement("Stage")]
    public List<Stage> Stages { get; set; }
```

You also have a few name inconsistencies.  These can be fixed by specifying an [element name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.elementname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [attribute name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributeattribute.attributename%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), for instance:

```
    [XmlAttribute("Selected")]
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
```

Thus the following set of classes seem to read in your sample XML successfully:

```
public class Process
{
    public string ProcessName { get; set; }
    public string HelpFile { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Stage")]
    public List<Stage> Stages { get; set; }
    public Process()
    {
        Stages = new List<Stage>();
    }
}

public class Stage
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string StageName { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("StagePage")]
    public string stagepage { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("Status")]
    public string StageStatus { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("Selected")]
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Step")]
    public List<Step> Steps { get; set; }
    public List<User> StageUsers { get; set; }

    public Stage() : this(null) { }

    public Stage(String name)
    {
        StageName = name;
        Steps = new List<Step>();
        StageUsers = new List<User>();
        IsSelected = true;
    }
}

public class Step
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string StepName { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string StepPage { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("Status")]
    public string StepStatus { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Task")]
    public List<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
    public List<User> StepUsers { get; set; }

    public Step() : this(null) { }

    public Step(String name)
    {
        StepName = name;
        Tasks = new List<Task>();
        StepUsers = new List<User>();
    }
}

public class Task
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string TaskName { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string TaskTip { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("Status")]
    public string TaskStatus { get; set; }

    public List<User> TaskUsers { get; set; }

    public Task() : this(null) { }

    public Task(String name)
    {
        TaskName = name;
        TaskUsers = new List<User>();
    }
}

public class User
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Alias { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Role { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Organization { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hi dbc, First of all thanks a lot. Before I accept your answer : Creating the XML was not my actual question .   I have nested GenerateXML() function calls in each of the classes that creates the above XML for me perfectly even if the method is inelegant . However , I am thankful for the method you suggested and I have used it since it helps reduce my code and is far more elegant.  Secondly , my main concern here is Deserialization i.e reading the Process XElement or XML into the respective objects in the classes and fields . I am sorry if my question's wording didn't convey this well enough.

Comment: Is there a way to create a Deserialize Extension method ? to read an XElement into the respective objects , fields i.e Stage , Step and their variables and so on. ?

Comment: hi dbc , I am stuck in a slight problem . I have a class called Reviewer which is basically an extension or subclass of the User class with two additional fields , eg string verdict and string comments . how shall i go about serializing that along with the included User information from superclass? I am able to do this without inheritance but my data is redundant in that case.

Comment: I have added my reviewer class at the end.

Comment: @PrasaanthNeelakandan - in that case I suggest asking another question.  The preferred format on stackoverflow is [one question per question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts), with each question being as simple as possible.  This question had lots of code which is likely out of date, so try to formulate a new question based on your current work.

Comment: okay sir. I shall do that . thank you . putting in my new question soon.