# List<T> to XML string Extension Method

Tags: c#, xml, list, csv, extension-methods

How can I create a extension method to convert my List of T to an XML string.
Where my T object's property becomes a xml tag and the property's value becomes the value within the xml tag. My T object has simple string properties, ie no collections or two dimensional object. That is all properties are string, int etc, ie one dimensional..no lists/arrays as a property.

Comment: Smells like an interview question!

Comment: An extension method is probably not the best choice; I would consider a class instead (that is abstracted by an interface). This will allow you to provide a class for XML-serialization and another one for CSV. The problem I see with an extension method is, that it must be implemented in a static class... and functionality that shall be polymorphic in some way, should not be static... just my two cents.

Comment: lol! it isn't. I am planning to converting my list object into a xml file via File.AppendAllText(".xml") by giving it a file extension. I basically have my data in a one level dimension in my object. I just need to see if there is a easier way to remove all my convertion code into a list extension method But maybe, I can remove the file part. Maybe just a xml output.

Comment: There's an extension method for Xml Serialization on [this page](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Implementing-Xml-b3223253)

Comment: @stuartd thanks let me try this out.

Comment: @Matze any examples?

Comment: @Matze I see your point, as I faced the " cannot be serialized because it does not have a parameterless constructor." issue.

Comment: @JeffJaffery Do you need this functionality as a one-way serializer; for instance in a logging-scenario, or do you also want to deserialize the data?

Comment: I just wanted to  serialize my object into xml and store the file. But I just got over the problem, when I used the IXMLSerialize object and implemented the xml write and read functions. So I am good now! So yes, It is somewhat a one way serializer as I don't send the info over the wire. This previous post helped. [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/267724/why-xml-serializable-class-need-a-parameterless-constructor)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to convert for example this kind of list:

```
List<int> Branches = new List<int>();
Branches.Add(1);
Branches.Add(2);
Branches.Add(3);
```

into this XML:

```
<Branches>
    <branch id="1" />
    <branch id="2" />
    <branch id="3" />
</Branches>
```

You can try this using LINQ:

```
List<int> Branches = new List<int>();
Branches.Add(1);
Branches.Add(2);
Branches.Add(3);

XElement xmlElements = new XElement("Branches", Branches.Select(i => new XElement("branch", new XAttribute("id", i))));
System.Console.Write(xmlElements);
System.Console.Read();
```

output:

```
<Branches>
  <branch id="1" />
  <branch id="2" />
  <branch id="3" />
</Branches>
```

**you need to include `using System.Xml.Linq;` namespace.**

**EDIT : To make files you can use this method**

```
 public string ToXML<T>(T obj)
 {
    using (StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter(new StringBuilder()))
    {
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        xmlSerializer.Serialize(stringWriter, obj);
        return stringWriter.ToString();
    }
 }
```

Comment: That creates an XML _fragment_, not a file

Comment: @stuartd - `XElement.Save(string fileName)` will take care of creating the file.

Comment: options if I didn't wanted to use attributes, but elements?

Comment: @JeffJaffery Maybe you can check this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387083.aspx

Comment: @VERYNET Worked like a charm. Thank you all for your answers.

Comment: @JeffJaffery It's a pleasure

Answer (score 2):

What you're talking about roughly translates to "serialization", and like most generic problems this one is solved. The framework certainly provides you with some tools for Xml Serialization.

Given a class:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public string Prop1 {get;set;}
    public string Prop2 {get;set; }
}
```

And an extension method:

```
public static class SerializationExtensions
{
    public static string ToXml<T>(this List<T> list)
    {
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<T>)); 

        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter(); 
        XmlTextWriter xmlWriter = new XmlTextWriter(stringWriter); 

        xmlWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented; 
        xmlSerializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, list); 

        return stringWriter.ToString();     
    }
}
```

A simple demo produces the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ArrayOfTestClass xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <TestClass>
    <Prop1>val1</Prop1>
    <Prop2>val2</Prop2>
  </TestClass>
  <TestClass>
    <Prop1>val1</Prop1>
    <Prop2>val2</Prop2>
  </TestClass>
  <TestClass>
    <Prop1>val1</Prop1>
    <Prop2>val2</Prop2>
  </TestClass>
</ArrayOfTestClass>
```

It would be trivial to serialize to a file rather than a string, but for demonstrating the usage it's easier to output as a string.

Live demo: http://rextester.com/AKIBNI2909

Comment: wow thank you! @Jamiec . I see the flaw in my question, i should just work with the strings and carry out the file IO elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Creating an extension method isn't that much different that a regular method.  You simply make the method static, if specify the first parameter (the object the method will extend) with the keyword "this".  The rest is just plan reflection.

```
    public static string GetXML<T>(this List<T> src)
    {
        // First, we have to determine the "Type" of the generic parameter.
        Type srcType = src.GetType();
        Type[] srcTypeGenArgs = srcType.GetGenericArguments();
        if (srcTypeGenArgs.Length != 1)
            throw new Exception("Only designed to work on classes with a single generic param.");
        Type genType = srcTypeGenArgs[0];

        // Get the properties for the generic Type "T".
        System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[] typeProps = genType.GetProperties(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.GetProperty);

        // Now, we loop through each item in the list and extract the property values.
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.AppendLine("<root>");
        for (int i = 0; i < src.Count; i++)
        {
            T listItem = src[i];
            for (int t = 0; t < typeProps.Length; t++)
            {
                object propVal = typeProps[t].GetValue(listItem, null); // Always pass "null" for the index param, if we're not dealing with some indexed type (like an array).
                string propValStr = (propVal != null ? propVal.ToString() : string.Empty);
                sb.AppendLine(string.Format("<{0}>{1}</{0}>", typeProps[t].Name, propValStr));
            }
        }
        sb.AppendLine("</root>");
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: The entire first bit of your code could be replaced with `var genType = typeof(T)`

Comment: Hmm..  I didn't think "typeof" worked on generic params.  I've always done it the long way, I guess.  Good to know.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Really helpful @MikeU