# Web API - error when returning list of complex objects

Tags: c#, serialization, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have created a webAPI controller method that looks the following:

```
 [HttpGet]
 public HttpResponseMessage RealEstates()
 {
     using (BoligsideDbContext context = new BoligsideDbContext())
     {
         List<RealEstateVm> realEstateVms = context.RealEstates.OrderByDescending(x => x.Id).ToList().Select(x => new RealEstateVm(x)).ToList();

          return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, realEstateVms);
     }
}
```

My VM looks the following:

```
public class RealEstateVm
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int Area { get; set; }
        public int Rooms { get; set; }
        public int Rent { get; set; }
        public string Picture { get; set; }
        public RealEstateType Type { get; set; } //this is just an enum
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public List<string> Images { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public string Phone2 { get; set; }
        public string OriginalUrl { get; set; }
        public string OriginalSource { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public int ZipCode { get; set; }
        public string StreetAddress { get; set; }
        public double Longtitude { get; set; }
        public double Latitude { get; set; }
}
```

However whenever I go to the endpoint I get the following error:

> Type 'Boligside.ViewModels.RealEstateVm' cannot be serialized.
>   Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and
>   marking all of its members you want serialized with the
>   DataMemberAttribute attribute. If the type is a collection, consider
>   marking it with the CollectionDataContractAttribute. See the Microsoft
>   .NET Framework documentation for other supported types.

What could be the issue? I don't see why I should have to mark my VM with [DataContractAttribute]?

By the way the complete error message is here:

> This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated
>   with it. The document tree is shown below.  An error
>   has occurred.  The 'ObjectContent`1' type
>   failed to serialize the response body for content type
>   'application/xml; charset=utf-8'. 
>   System.InvalidOperationException
>     An error has
>   occurred.  Type
>   'Boligside.ViewModels.RealEstateVm' cannot be serialized. Consider
>   marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all
>   of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute
>   attribute. If the type is a collection, consider marking it with the
>   CollectionDataContractAttribute. See the Microsoft .NET Framework
>   documentation for other supported types. 
>   
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException
>     at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.DataContractCriticalHelper.ThrowInvalidDataContractException(String
>   message, Type type) at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.DataContractCriticalHelper.CreateDataContract(Int32
>   id, RuntimeTypeHandle typeHandle, Type type) at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.DataContractCriticalHelper.GetDataContractSkipValidation(Int32
>   id, RuntimeTypeHandle typeHandle, Type type) at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerContext.GetDataContract(Int32
>   id, RuntimeTypeHandle typeHandle) at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.InternalSerialize(XmlWriterDelegator
>   xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean isDeclaredType, Boolean writeXsiType,
>   Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle) at
>   WriteArrayOfRealEstateVmToXml(XmlWriterDelegator , Object ,
>   XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext , CollectionDataContract ) at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContract.WriteXmlValue(XmlWriterDelegator
>   xmlWriter, Object obj, XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext context) at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.WriteDataContractValue(DataContract
>   dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj,
>   RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle) at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeWithoutXsiType(DataContract
>   dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj,
>   RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle) at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalWriteObjectContent(XmlWriterDelegator
>   writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver) at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalWriteObject(XmlWriterDelegator
>   writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver) at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.WriteObjectHandleExceptions(XmlWriterDelegator
>   writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver) at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.WriteObject(XmlWriter
>   writer, Object graph) at
>   System.Net.Http.Formatting.XmlMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type
>   type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content) at
>   System.Net.Http.Formatting.XmlMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStreamAsync(Type
>   type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content,
>   TransportContext transportContext, CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken) --- End of stack trace from previous location where
>   exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler.d__1b.MoveNext()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the error said, It cannot be serialized and consider adding the data contract attribute..

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
[DataContract]
public class RealEstateVm
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int Area { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int Rooms { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int Rent { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Picture { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public RealEstateType Type { get; set; } //this is just an enum
        public string Address { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public List<string> Images { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Phone2 { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string OriginalUrl { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string OriginalSource { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string City { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int ZipCode { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string StreetAddress { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public double Longtitude { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public double Latitude { get; set; }
}
```

More information about [Data Contracts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Well that works but I fail to see why this is necessary.
I distinctively remember not having to add datamember attributes to simple types.

Comment: @JeppeKoefod `DataContractSerializer`, which is what Web API uses by default, is opt-in; `XmlSerializer` is opt-out.

Comment: On http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization it is stated that "By default, all public properties and fields are included in the serialized JSON. To omit a property or field, decorate it with the JsonIgnore attribute."

Comment: @JeppeKoefod You're not serializing as JSON, rather you're serializing as XML. Check your error message. Make sure you are including the appropriate `Accept` header in your request.

Comment: @KennethK.
Ahh I see. I've changed it to JSON now and it works perfectly without the attributes. Thanks!

Comment: @JeppeKoefod Yeah, since the formatters are added in a paricular order, and XML is the first formatter added (out of the box), if you don't specify an `Accept` you end up with XML.

Answer (score 7):

Your DTO class is missing an parameterless constructor. See here : [Why XML-Serializable class need a parameterless constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267724/why-xml-serializable-class-need-a-parameterless-constructor)
(Sorry to wake up this question but I have the same problem right now)

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks.
Another important note is that all your properties must have public setters in order to be desalinized

Answer (score 3):

Calling the API from browser will not set Accept Header to application/json, so the api will use XmlFormatter which uses DataContractSerializer by default, which is opt-in.

you can change that default behavior for XML like this

```
// XML Serializer Settings
var xml = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter;
// use UseXmlSerializer because we use opu-out in our model classes
xml.UseXmlSerializer = true;
```