# Serialization not working in C#

Tags: c#, serialization

I have a structure like.

An interface

```
interface ITest
{
}
```

class implementing that interface

```
class Test : ITest
{
}
```

One class with parametrized constructor, and M1 method

```
class WithConstructor
{
    public WithConstructor(ITest test)
    {
    }
    public void M1()
    {
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["view"] = test;
    }
}
```

class `Test` creates it's object and calls it's `M1` method as below.

```
WithConstructor wc = new WithConstructor(this);
wc.M1();
```

but it gives me error

> Type 'X' in Assembly
>   'Y,
>   Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is not marked
>   as serializable.

So I marked class `Test` serializable using `[Serializable]` but still the same error. How can I get rid oof it?

Comment: Add a non-parameterised constructor. Even though it is `Private`.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal any reason sir?

Comment: How are you storing the test object in the constructor?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/267724/why-xml-serializable-class-need-a-parameterless-constructor

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal thanks, will implement it :)