# What role plays constructor in xmlserialize class?

Tags: c#, xml, xmlserializer, xml-deserialization

I have been trying to deserialize xml file while ago and had some problem that the serializer cannot find root element. Then I created constructor and everything works fine.

Can anyone explain me please why is this happening?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why XML-Serializable class need a parameterless constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267724/why-xml-serializable-class-need-a-parameterless-constructor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `XmlSerializer` will create instances of your types via reflection. To do so it must be able to *instantiate* your classes, which is by using its **default-constructor**. If you don´t have any, serializer can´t create the instance.

This is more or less the same thing, as serializer will do also:

```
Type type = // read type from XmlReader
var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
property.SetProperty(instance, theValue);
```

`Activator.CreateInstance` however assumes a parameterless (=default) constructor. So if your class has another constructor defined, `Activator` can´t create the instance as it has no knowledge on the parameters to call the *existing* constructor, see here:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string MyString { get; set; }
    public MyClass(string someString) { this.MyString = someString; }
}
```

Here `Activator` tries to create an instance of `MyClass` *without* any parameter, as it simply doesn´t know better. However `MyClass` excepts a string as parameter, making that call to fail.

If on the other hand `MyClass` has no constructor at all, the default-constructor is *implicitely* created for you. In this case you can savely create the instance via reflection.