# Xml Serialization - System.InvalidOperationException: Is it not possible to serialize 'this'?

Tags: c#, serialization, xml-serialization

Hopefully this question isn't too obvious, however I'm taking my first steps into the topic of serialization and couldn't find an explanation for the following behaviour:

I wanted to serialize a class to test if I set up everything correctly. For this I took [the code from this tutorial](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/483055/XML-Serialization-and-Deserialization-Part-1) and adapted it as follows:

```
    private void SerializePresets(string path)
    {
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClass));
        using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(path))
        {
            xmlSerializer.Serialize(writer, this);
        }
    }
```

This method lies within `MyClass` and is also called from there. This gives me the following exception:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   System.Xml.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: There was an error reflecting type
>   'MyClass'.

Since `MyClass` holds other class object as properties first I thought I have to make those serializabel too, however the exception still persists. 
So, my guess is, that it is impossible serialize `this`, however I couldn't find a confirmation to this guess.

EDIT: This property causes the issue according to the inner exception:

```
[XmlArray("VolumePresetList"), XmlArrayItem(typeof(LinearAxisColorPresetsModel), ElementName = "VolumePresetList")]
public ObservableCollection<LinearAxisColorPresetsModel> VolumePresetList { get; set; }
```

Comment: Can you add your definition of `MyClass`?

Comment: Did you take a look at the inner exception?

Comment: @spodger I'll try to paste it here, but I have to take a look at it first and rename some things, since it is for a classified project..

Comment: The thing is, what you are trying is perfectly possible as long as `MyClass` is defined appropriately.

Comment: @Dirk thanks for the tipp (silly me), found the Property that causes the issue and will edit OP

Comment: What is the definition of `LinearAxisColorPresetsModel`?

Comment: Found the problem and added it as answer, thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of the inner exceptions (thanks for the tip again) I could find out the reason why the serialization failed.

The class `LinearAxisColorPresetsModel`did not have a parameterless Constructor, which caused this issue.

Simply adding

```
/// <summary>
/// Default Constructor
/// </summary>
private LinearAxisColorPresetsModel()
{

}
```

to this class solved the problem for me. What remains is to find out the reason, why we must have a parameterless Constructor.

EDIT: [Found the reasoning behind this behaviour in this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267724/why-xml-serializable-class-need-a-parameterless-constructor)

Comment: Interestingly Boost serialisation for C++ also needs classes to have a parameterless constructor. In that it's because deserialisation works in a similar way to that described in the link you've added. I guess this is necessary for serialisation that is not an inherent part of the language (XML for C#, Boost for C++); as a library it has no knowledge of how an object get layed out in memory, and so has use the constructor to create it. At least in C# the setters can do useful things. In C++ there are no setters, and so post-deserialisation work has to be called manually; room for errors...

Answer (score 1):

You can use this.  It must be one of the properties like a Dictionary that doesn't serialize.  See my example below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication103
{
    class Program
    {

        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
            myClass.Serialize(FILENAME);

        }
    }
    public class MyClass
    {
         public string test { get; set; }

         public void Serialize(string filename)
         {
             SerializePresets(filename);
         }
         private void SerializePresets(string path)
         {
             XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClass));
             using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(path))
             {
                 xmlSerializer.Serialize(writer, this);
             }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Is there a way to find out which of the properties causes the issue?

Comment: I usually comment out properties until I find the one causing the issue.  I do not think you StackTrace exception message will help, but you can try.