# Web API middleware short circuiting unexpectedly

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

The following code is part of an error handling middleware, whose goal is to provide consistent formatting for the client even if an error is thrown.

I am trying to serialize a response as XML when the `Accept` header is set to `application/xml`, otherwise return JSON. This article helped get me started: https://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/handling-errors-in-asp.net-core-web-api

```
if (context.Request.Headers["Accept"] == "application/xml")
{
    context.Response.ContentType = "application/xml";

    using (var stringwriter = new StringWriter())
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(response.GetType());
        serializer.Serialize(stringwriter, response);
        await context.Response.WriteAsync(stringwriter.ToString());
    }
}
else {
    context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response);
    await context.Response.WriteAsync(json);
}
```

The `else` block works as expected. If I set a breakpoint on the line where the `XmlSerializer` is declared, execution halts. If I set a breakpoint on the following line, the breakpoint is never hit; a response has already been sent to the client.

My middleware is configured like this:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/error/{0}");
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/error/500");
        app.UseHsts();
        app.UseMiddleware<ErrorWrappingMiddleware>();
        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

Why is a response returned to the client before `context.Response.WriteAsync(stringwriter.ToString());` is called in the `if` block?

Comment: WebAPi has content-negotiation built in (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/formatting?view=aspnetcore-2.2), Is there any reason to write this middleware?

Comment: I've seen this page and added `AddXmlSerializerFormatters()` to my configuration, but when an error is returned (status code 500 for instance) the response body is blank. I want a consistently formatted response body, hence the additional middleware.

Comment: When using XML formatters, return only types don't return IEnumerable of types this will throw exception.

Comment: Can we get a more complete example? Also what happens if you set a try catch around var serializer = new XmlSerializer(response.GetType());
        serializer.Serialize(stringwriter, response);
        await context.Response.WriteAsync(stringwriter.ToString());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem, it was a silly mistake.

To test 500 errors, I was intentionally adding a property to a model that didn't have a corresponding column in the database. This throws a `SqlException` on an invalid column name. There was however a second exception I missed that told me exactly what the problem was:

`ApiResponse cannot be serialized because it does not have a parameterless constructor.`

This occurred in the call to `serializer.Serialize(stringwriter, response)`. The example I referenced creates an `ApiResponse` class (the `response` I attempted to serialize). However this class does not have a parameterless constructor in the example I was learning from, and I wasn't aware this was necessary until I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/267727/5472966) answer. This second exception halted execution, but since I forgot to turn on development mode and I was trying to throw an exception, I didn't notice the second one.