# XML cannot be serialized - parameterless constructor error, even with constructor

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I'm trying to serialize an object to xml using `XmlSerializer` but keep getting this error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: [MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter] cannot be serialized because it does not have a parameterless constructor.
```

I followed the solution to [why xml serializable class need a parameterless constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267724/why-xml-serializable-class-need-a-parameterless-constructor) which seems to have solved the problem for everyone else, but I still get an error. When I add `public MyClass()` it gives me `'MyClass.MyClass()' must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial`, so I add a body and the first error comes back.

Note that originally there aren't any constructors, parameterless or otherwise, so I don't understand why it isn't just automatically creating its own.

What am I doing wrong?

*Code added:*

**MyFile.cs**

```
public async Task Save(MyClass xmlObj)
{
    XmlSerializer xmlSer = new XmlSerializer(this.GetType()); //I think the problem is likely to be here
    StringWriter strWriter = new StringWriter();

    xmlSer.Serialize(strWriter, xmlObj);
    objToUpdate.ColName = (strWriter.ToString());
    await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

**File.cs**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> SaveData(params...)
{
    await new MyFile<MySqlParameter>(accessParam, dbContext).Save(xmlObj);
}
```

Comment: The issue is surely that `MySqlParameter` can't be serialised, not `MyClass` - so why are you adding a constructor to `MyClass`?  And what version of `MySql` are you using? Because [`MySqlParameter` *does* have a parameterless constructor](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/8.0/html/M_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlParameter__ctor.htm). Can you post a compilable reproduction of your problem?

Comment: Why would it be trying to serialise `MySqlParameter`? That's only the data being sent to the db when saving, it's in the parent method, not with the `XmlSerializer`

Comment: are you tried to change your constructor to ``private`` or ``internal``?

Comment: Yes, tried all three

Comment: `Why would it be trying to serialise` - I don't know why, but the error message clearly states that it *is* being serialised. You will need to post some code.

Comment: Added basic code, let me know if it's missing something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out...

I had been creating a new `XmlSerializer` and passing in a parameter as posted in a SO answer:

`XmlSerializer xmlSer = new XmlSerializer(this.GetType());`

When really it works perfectly fine to use the same `XmlSerializer` as the deserialization:

`XmlSerializer objSer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClass));`

Answer (score 1):

You should have added

```
public MyClass(){}
```

to the class. There is a difference between no body and an empty body which is what you want on this constructor.

Comment: From my question: *so I add a body and the first error comes back* - I already tried that

Comment: as @Matthew asked, please post the code for the class you're trying to serialize, it does look like you trying to serialize a none searilizable object