# What are the rules for the parameterless constructor invoked by XmlSerializer

Tags: .net, xml-serialization, default-constructor

Under the sub-heading "XML Serialization Considerations" [at this link it says...](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/introducing-xml-serialization)

> A class must have a parameterless constructor to be serialized by
> XmlSerializer.

This is actually misleading. In fact you do not need to declare a parameterless constructor (default constructor). Answers on stackoverflow.com indicate that  you do not need to declare the parameterless constructor unless you declare a parameterized constructor. Once a parameterized constructor is declared then you need to also declare the parameterless constructor.

I am interested in the parameterless constructor statement block.

My test program indicates that in one case it is harmless to leave the parameterless constructor empty and restoration is successful. In another case member data assignment in the parameterless constructor seems to be overwritten by the restoration.  In another case a member data object graph can be augmented in the parameterless constructor and that augmentation precedes restored objects. Perhaps the rule is that if the member data is a reference it will be restored if the reference is null but if the parameterless constructor statement block makes it non-null then the restoration will augment the object at that reference. **Edit:** I just realized the rule is wrong because actually string is a reference type and my test shows a string reference does not survive restoration.

What are the rules for the parameterless constructor statement block? (If you know where this is documented then please post a link.)

```
public class BlobEmpty
{
    public string name;
    public List<int> list;
    internal BlobEmpty() 
    {
        // demonstrate that XmlSerializer does not require any content in the 
        // statement block of the parameterless constructor
        Console.Beep(); // this gets executed upon deserialization 
                        // but this statement block is essentially empty
        // ** note that I do not instantiate the list of int **
    }
    internal BlobEmpty(string name) 
    { 
        this.list = new List<int>(); 
        this.name = name; 
    }
}
public class BlobPopulate
{
    public string name;
    public List<int> list;
    internal BlobPopulate()
    {
        Console.Beep(); // this gets executed upon deserialization
        this.list = new List<int>(); // this object will survive the restoration
        this.list.Add(999); // this item will be in front of the restored items
        this.name = "garbage"; // this string will not survive the restoration
    }
    internal BlobPopulate(string name)
    {
        this.list = new List<int>();
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

For the sake of completeness here is the test program...

```
private static void TestDeserialization0(string name, string fileName)
{
    var c = new BlobEmpty(name);
    c.list.Add(123); 
    c.list.Add(456);
    Serialize(c, fileName);
    var restored = (BlobEmpty)Deserialize(typeof(BlobEmpty), fileName);
    Debug.Assert(restored.name.Equals(name));
    Debug.Assert(restored.list.Count == 2);
    Debug.Assert(restored.list[0].Equals(123));
    Debug.Assert(restored.list[1].Equals(456));
}
private static void TestDeserialization1(string name, string fileName)
{
    var c = new BlobPopulate(name);
    c.list.Add(123);
    c.list.Add(456);
    Serialize(c, fileName);
    var restored = (BlobPopulate)Deserialize(typeof(BlobPopulate), fileName);
    Debug.Assert(restored.name.Equals(name));
    Debug.Assert(restored.list.Count == 3);
    Debug.Assert(restored.list[0].Equals(999));
    Debug.Assert(restored.list[1].Equals(123));
    Debug.Assert(restored.list[2].Equals(456));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> This is actually misleading. In fact you do not need to declare a parameterless constructor (default constructor). Answers on [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com) indicate that you do not need to declare the parameterless constructor unless you declare a parameterized constructor. Once a parameterized constructor is declared then you need to also declare the parameterless constructor.

It's not misleading. Without any other constructors, the C# compiler automatically **adds in** the default parameter-less constructor. It's still declared, just not by you.

---

In `BlobEmpty` the serializer will check the `list` and sees it is `null` so it will instantiate it. Then it will call `Add` to insert the new elements.

In `BlobPopulate` the serializer will take `list` and see it is not `null`. It will call `Add` on the existing list to insert the new elements.

Any other properties (not `IEumerable`) will always be overwritten.